# Has anyone else had trouble with IE9 and jQueryUI?

Tags: internet-explorer, jquery-ui, internet-explorer-9

I work with a lot of jQuery UI code and IE9 seems to slow down to a crawl everytime I browse a page with jQueryUI on it.

You could try it out on the jQueryUI demo pages @ http://jqueryui.com/demos/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the IE9 JavaScript engine (and the rest of it for that matter) has many, *many* outstanding issues.  However, I wouldn't spend **any** time looking into them, wait for a later beta (or RC) in which (hopefully) Microsoft fixes some of these.

This isn't specific to jQuery UI at all, *most* pages with complicated JavaScript crawl at the moment.